# VOLEY, enviando todos los datos de una tabla de SQLite

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

Quiero mandar todos los datos de la base de datos SQLite de la siguiente forma:

```
@Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
            SQLiteDatabase db = basededatos.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.query("aguacate", new String[] {"calibre","precio","porcentaje","resultado",},null, null, null, null, null);
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                //Recorremos el cursor hasta que no haya más registros
                do {
                    parameters.put("calibre",cursor.getString(1));
                    parameters.put("precio", cursor.getString(2));
                    parameters.put("porcentaje", cursor.getString(3));
                    parameters.put("resultado", cursor.getString(4));
                } while(cursor.moveToNext());
            }
            return parameters;
        }
    };
    requestQueue.add(request);
```

Pero, ¿cómo puedo poner el

```
requestQueue.add(request);
```

dentro del ciclo while? No me deja, ¿existe  alguna solución?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dentro del ciclo `while` no te va a dejar dado que está dentro de la sección donde se asignan los parámetros que se enviarán en el `StringRequest`

Según entiendo tu pregunta, requieres realizar una petición por medio del `StringRequest` para cada registro de tu consulta, para lo cual te recomiendo que primero hagas una función que itere tu consulta, consumas otra función que se manda llamar con cada registro encontrado, para lo cual propondría algo así:

**Código de la función que genera los resultados para cada petición**

```
public void ProcessQuery(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = basededatos.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query("aguacate", new String[] {"calibre","precio","porcentaje","resultado",},null, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        //Recorremos el cursor hasta que no haya más registros
        do {
            final Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
            parameters.put("calibre",cursor.getString(1));
            parameters.put("precio", cursor.getString(2));
            parameters.put("porcentaje", cursor.getString(3));
            parameters.put("resultado", cursor.getString(4));
            //Por cada registro encontrado se obtienen los parámetros y se envían a la función que procesa la petición por medio del StringRequest
            ProcessRequest(parameters);
        } while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }
}
```

**Código de la función que ejecuta las peticiones**

```
private void ProcessRequest(Map<String, String> parameters){
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, UPLOAD_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String s) {
                    //Showing toast message of the response
                    Toast.makeText(upload.this, s , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                    //Showing toast
                    Toast.makeText(upload.this, volleyError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            return parameters;
        }
    };

    //Creating a Request Queue
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    //Adding request to the queue
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

También te recomiendo que realices el manejo de variables en caso de que alguna sea nula y no se genere una excepción

**Actualización**

Se declara la varible `parameters` como `final` para que no marque errores el código

Comment: Hola gracias por responder soy nuevo en android realmente. me marca error en esta parte:

                return parameters;

Comment: ¿Qué error te marca?

Comment: variable `parameters` is accessed from within inner class, needs to be declared final.

Comment: Bien, si te das cuenta el mismo error te va diciendo qué es lo que se tiene que corregir. Voy a corregir mi código y a la variable `parameters` la voy a declarar como `final` y ya no te debe causar error

Comment: Se me cierra la app. mira como tengo el codigo:
`FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fabEnviar);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ProcessQuery();
}`

ya declare como final y nada.

Comment: Necesitaría saber en qué línea y todo el StackTrace del error para determinar con mayor exactitud por qué falla

Comment: El problema era lo siguiente lo comento.
            `parameters.put("calibre",cursor.getString(1));
            parameters.put("precio", cursor.getString(2));
            parameters.put("porcentaje", cursor.getString(3));
            parameters.put("resultado", cursor.getString(4));`

lo unico que hice fue iniciar en `0`
`parameters.put("calibre",cursor.getString(0));`

Me funciona perfecto. Muchas Gracias!

Comment: Una pregunta más, puedo hacer un tipo loader para que el usuario vea que se estan mandando, donde lo pondria?